# EPA (EasyPG Assistant): How to encrypt for *two* of my own keys? OR How are key-ids used to select keys

Tags: gpg, epa

I want to tell epa to encrypt for *two* of my public keys. (stored in two different places). I have this at the top of the file:

```
# -*- mode:org; epa-file-encrypt-to: ("arthur@ul___dt.com") -*-
```

which causes it to select the first *one* key for that email. If i run `epa-file-select-keys` I can choose the two keys I want, though only for that session. I would prefer it remember this decision in the file so I don't have to remember to do this each time on each new computer this file is opened on.

1. How can I specify two keys by key-id on that line?
2. What is the **actual syntax of the strings in the epa-file-encrypt-to** variable? Is it defined somewhere? How are specific keys selected from this string

PS: these keys have the same user-id string and I'd prefer not to have to change that.

PPS: there is also a revoked key with the same email that it needs to not choose. I have tried on emacs 24.3.1 and emacs 25-snapshot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
# -*- mode:org; epa-file-encrypt-to: ("arthur@ul___dt.com" "foo@bar.baz") -*-
```

When a mail address is associated to several keys switch to the key ids.  E.g. a call to `epa-file-select-keys` reveals key ids.  The header line with fake key ids looks like:

```
# -*- mode:org; epa-file-encrypt-to: ("12345678ABCDEF00" "12345678ABCDEF01") -*-
```

I have not found a syntax-definition for variable epa-file-encrypt-to.  I guess it's supposed to be a list containing identifiers for keys as they can be understood by the gpg program.

Comment: and it also works if you mix email addressed and the long ids

Comment: I had tried this using the short id's before asking, and though it didn't work

Comment: that comma there confused the hell out of my emacs, and i had to reencrypt the file in the command line to get rid of it. are you sure it's needed?

Comment: That comma looks wrong. Typically there is no comma in lisp lists AFAICT. Sorry for the inconvenience. I corrected the answer. See the respective edit of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

for me leaving the comma away work. Looks like this:

```
# -*- mode:org; epa-file-encrypt-to: ("arthur@ul___dt.com" "foo@bar.baz") -*-
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.